# SonarQube Maven Analysis is not available in jenkins job UI

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

versions:

jenkins: 1.651.1
sonarqube: 6.0
jenkins plugin "SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins" 2.3

manage jenkins: section sonarqube instance config:
[image]

sonarqube runner configs:
[image]

I only see MSBuild scanner in build-step config of a job:
[image]

I suspect this is due to old version of jenkins and old jenkins sonarqube scanner plugin. Can you please confirm. Or I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven), you're going to use a standard Maven step for this.